# Can't Install BOTIM android application in Oreo

Tags: applications, google-play-store, motorola-moto-g, 8.0-oreo, video-calling

I have Moto G5 with android Oreo OS, I am trying to install BOTIM application from play store, play store able to download it, but it gives error during installation (Can't install BOTIM app). Even I have tried to clear the play store cache and app data with multiple restarts, still I am facing the issue. Also I tried to uninstall the Play Store updates and made Play Store as factory version, this doesn't workout either.

Pls suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have identified the issue. I mounted the SD card as Internal memory. Due to this the app (Not only this app, even ) failed to install in to memory. I remounted SD card as portable storage, then i am able to download and install the app.